# How to draw this rectangle with numbers along its edge?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape

I'm trying to draw this picture, which is created from MS Excel.

[image]

I'm only able to draw a simple rectangle

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (7,0) -- (7,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Could you please elaborate on how to draw such figure? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=0.7]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (7,3) (3,3) -- (3,0) -- (0,3) 
 (0.2,0.2) node[above right,font=\Huge]{$0$}
foreach \X [count=\Y] in {1,3,7} {(0,3.5-\Y) node[red,left] {$\X$}
 (-0.5+\Y,3) node[red,above] {$\X$}}
foreach \X [count=\Y] in {2,4,5,6} {(2.5+\Y,3) node[above] {$\X$}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As for the code in your comment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=0.7]     
\draw (0,0) rectangle (6,3) (3,3) -- (3,0) -- (0,3)     
(0.4,0.4) node[above right,font=\Huge]{$\mathbf 0$}     
foreach \X/\Z [count=\Y] in {i_1,\cdots/\vdotswithin{i_1},i_k} {(0,3.5-\Y)
 node[red,left] {$\Z$}  
(-0.5+\Y,3) node[red,above] {$\X$}}     
foreach \X [count=\Y] in
{i_{k+1},\cdots,i_N} {(2.5+\Y,3) node[above] {$\X$}};   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried to modify your code to include the [dots](https://imgur.com/a/UboG19i). The horizontal dots is fine, but the vertical dots is not as expected. I guess this is because they are the same. Could you please help me edit this code to have the vertical dots.

Comment: This is how I modify your code: `\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=0.7]
 \draw (0,0) rectangle (6,3) (3,3) -- (3,0) -- (0,3) 
 (0.4,0.4) node[above right,font=\Huge]{$\mathbf 0$}
 foreach \X [count=\Y] in {i_1,\cdots,i_k} {(0,3.5-\Y) node[red,left] {$\X$}
  (-0.5+\Y,3) node[red,above] {$\X$}}
 foreach \X [count=\Y] in {i_{k+1},\cdots,i_N} {(2.5+\Y,3) node[above] {$\X$}};
 \end{tikzpicture}`.

Answer (score 2):

For example, this plain TeX code creates the numbers around the rectangle:

```
\hbox to150bp{\def\h{\hskip0pt plus2fil}\hfil 1\h 3\h 7\h 2\h 4\h 5\h 6\hfil}
\medskip
\hbox{\llap{\vbox to30bp{\def\h#1{\hbox{#1}}\h1\vfil\h3\vfil\h7}\kern8bp}%
  \pdfliteral{q 1 j 1 J 0 0 m 150 0 l 150 30 l 0 30 l s 60 30 m 60 0 l 0 30 l S Q}}

\bye
```

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain it with a simple `tabular` and some tools from latex (`array,diagbox,multirow`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, diagbox, multirow}

\begin{document}

{\sffamily\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{ >{\color{red}}c|*{3}{>{\color{red}}c}|*{4}{c}|}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & 1 & 3 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\color{red}7} & 2 & 4 & 5 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{6} \\ \cline{2-8}
 1 & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{\diagbox[height=3.85pc, width=4.3pc]{\huge 0}{}}}& & & & \\
 3 & & & & & & & \\
 7 & & & & & & & \\[-0.4pt] \cline{2-8}
\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

[image]